# How to Search ArrayList For Integer and Remove It If It Exists In Java

Tags: java, for-loop, search, arraylist

In my program I have to to be able to remove items from an arrayList. The user inputs a number and then if it exists in the arrayList it is removed. When I press the remove button the program would crash if it weren't for my try and catch statements, does anyone know what I should change for the removal to work properly?

```
public class SumElements extends javax.swing.JFrame {
ArrayList <Integer> values = new ArrayList();
```

...

```
private void removeButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    try {
        //declare variables
        int searchVal = Integer.parseInt(valueInput.getText());

        //search array for inputed value
        int index = Collections.binarySearch(values, searchVal);

        if (index >= 0){
            //clear outputArea
            outputArea.setText(null);
            outputLabel.setText(null);

            //remove from array
            values.remove(valueInput.getText());

            //display updated values
            Collections.sort(values);
            for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++)
            {
                outputArea.setText(outputArea.getText() + values.get(i) + "\n");
            }
            //clear input
            valueInput.setText(null);    
        }
        else {
                outputLabel.setText("Data not found. Please try again.");
            }
    }
    //set default
    catch (NumberFormatException a)
    {
     outputLabel.setText("Please input a valid number.");
    }
}
```

Comment: it should be  values.remove(index);

Comment: What's the point of sorting after removing an element?

Comment: Post your stack trace.

Comment: @ravthiru True, but that doesn't explain why it's crashing.

Comment: Why are you overwriting `outputArea` for each element?

Comment: If your question is why you're getting a `NumberFormatException`, you've answered it yourself. You need to input a valid number.

Comment: @shmosel Sorry i'm not sure what you mean by stack trace, I'm kind of new to this. I'm clearing outputArea so that I don't end up with the same output repeated every time I hit the remove button, so that it only ever shows the values of the arrayList once. When I input a valid number ex. 4 and I press my remove button nothing happens except it says "Please enter a valid number" as a result of my try-catch statement, something is causing it to crash. I can post all of the code that I've written for the program so far if that would help?

Comment: @ravthiru thanks that worked, the remove function works properly now.

Comment: @shmosel thanks for the help, it's all good now.